# Replacing water heater gas control valve

Tags: water-heater, valve, replacement, natural-gas

First let me summarize my questions, then provide detail:

**Summary:**

- Can a newer gas control valve be installed on an older water heater?
- As an individual who has never attempted something like this and never worked with natural gas am I completely insane for even contemplating a DIY project?

  - Read details below in regards to why I am considering replacing the valve myself.
- Also seeking general guidelines / instruction on replacing a gas control valve, especially anything specific to my model.

  - Fair number of YouTube videos that make it look easy
  - My model is an A.O. Smith GCV 50 100
- Water heater still seems to be in decent condition; a replacement valve should get me at least a few more years (and hot water until the real problem can be fixed)

  - There is no brown water indicating tank corrosion
  - There are no apparent leaks from the tank
  - The water heater also already has an expansion tank installed on it. You can barely make it out behind the flue.

**Details:**

My wife and I bought a house last summer that is now 10 years old. Our natural gas water heater gave up the ghost last weekend.

Let me show you what my utility closet looks like:

[image: Utility Closet]

Note the AWESOME freon line that runs *directly* in front of my water heater, therefore preventing it from being easily replaced without rerouting the line. It could probably be done, but that runs a risk of damaging my HVAC.

I was quoted about $1600 to replace the water heater by two different plumbers; one says he can "manhandle" the water heater out, the other wants the line rerouted before he will try (quoted me $1475 for the job). I'm afraid that the "manhandle" route might end up "manhandling" more than just the water heater.

One plumber also quoted me $700 for replacing the gas control valve. I already replaced the thermocouple on my own and I don't think it was ever part of the problem. I should definitely buy a multi-meter...

I can purchase the gas control for about $200 and I am confident that I can make the repair, however I am nervous about working with natural gas.

Here is the gas control valve now:

[image: Gas Control Valve]

So can I use a newer gas control valve or should I get an identical replacement? Should I spend the $2000 + dollars to replace the entire thing or attempt a repair on my own, have the freon line fixed and then wait for the tank to go?

I am looking for instruction, direct advice and opinions more informed than my own.

Here is the model information for the water heater as well:

[image: Model Information]

Comment: Worst case scenario - you buy a gas control valve and can't get it installed.  You should be working entirely beyond the supply shut-off valve, so you can just turn leave gas off and have a plumber come out and complete the repair.

Comment: That is how I feel about it. Plus, the part is less than $200 and I believe that I can find a friend with some experience working with gas.

Comment: Do you have the part number for the gas valve or a link to it on Amazon?

Comment: @BrandenGriffitts I purchased the item from [Amazon at this URL](http://www.amazon.com/A-O-Smith-9000246005-Gas-Valve/dp/B00EZHKTMS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did it! And it turned out not to be the problem...

Things to note:

- You may need a rubber mallet to remove the old gas control valve.

  - I had to bang on the T junction pipe to the left of the valve to get it unscrewed
- Here is the joint compound that I used

  - [image]
- I also used teflon tape.
- Start by wrapping the teflon tape into the threads of the compression fittings 2 or three times
- "Frost" the threads of the male ends of the fittings liberally; a little too much joint compund (pipe dope) won't hurt

  - Try not to get it *inside* the pipe however, so stay away from the very very end of the connector

And of course, be **sure** to turn off your gas when working with it, drain your water heater if it is an older style model (like mine) and be careful putting everything back together.

**My problem:** My problem ended up being the thermocouple. The replacement pilot light assembly I had installed just 8 weeks ago ended up having a faulty thermocouple. Obviously I should have taken more time to test the thermocouple rather than spending all the time and money on a new valve. Ah well! I'll be putting in a new anode shortly and hopefully I will get another 3-5 years out of this water heater. Enough time to take care of the freon line when the budget allows...

Also worth mentioning, I found an identical gas control valve from a vendor on Amazon. Ever since I got the new pilot light assembly in place it has been working just fine.